# Getting exception in Trigger : System.QueryException: Non-selective query against large object type (more than 100000 rows)

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm getting exception in following query,

```
List<Background_Search__c> lstbgs = [SELECT id FROM Background_Search__c WHERE
                                     AIT_Selected_for_Random_Search_Audit__c = true 
AND CreatedDate>2014-12-04T00:00:00.000Z ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You attempt to query big collection and too many records are potential match.
Your query in Salesforce need to be as selective as possible - this mean return only records that match your criteria and it should use field mark as "indexed"(Id, externalId etc).

Please check:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm

Comment: Thanks for your reply but when i tried same query on developer console it shows only 5 records this time than how can i ensure that it returns big collection ?

Comment: Its not about number of returned records but rather size of collection you query against. You see - the bigger table you query is, more operations need to be performed to filter out records. You should try use some Indexed field in your WHERE statement(if possible).